# WP_QUERY to display woocommerce products whose author IS the logged in user

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

I am creating a custom account page where I want to display products that the logged-in user is the author of.

I have users creating their own products via gravity forms.

I'd like to create a plugin or query that can be used to show the products that they have created. The query should show the standard product view from woocommerce including add to cart.

I'll be changing add to cart to custom text and skipping the cart and taking them direct to checkout.

This functionality is outside of my knowledge base and I appreciate any guidance.